# Add to existing slide, instead of new slide

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I copy paste my ranges from XL to PPT.
It creates new slides and adds range as picture.

How can I make it paste range to existing slide, instead of creating slide?

Right now it loops and paste copied picture to new slide.
I get error in this line: "Set PPslide = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1)"

Thanks.

```
  Dim PP As PowerPoint.Application
  Dim PPpres As PowerPoint.Presentation
  Dim PPslide As Object
  Dim k As Long, i As Long
  Dim PpShape As PowerPoint.Shape
  Dim SlideTitle As String
  Dim SlideNum As Integer
  Dim WSrow As Long
  Dim Sh As Shape
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim myShape As Object
  
'Open PowerPoint and create new presentation
Set PP = GetObject(class, "PowerPoint.Application")
PP.Visible = True
Set PPpres = PP.Presentations.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\Mac\Desktop\test\PPT.pptx")
k = 1

    For i = 6 To Cells(70, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column Step 10

       With Cells(70, i)
    .Resize(1, 10).CopyPicture Appearance:=xlPrinter, Format:=xlPicture
                    DoEvents
                    DoEvents
    .Offset(15, 0).PasteSpecial
                    DoEvents
                    DoEvents
End With


 'Give the last pasted picture a name.
                ActiveSheet.Pictures(ActiveSheet.Pictures.Count).Name = "Element" & k
                


' Here you're adding a new slide, which you've said you don't want.
' Comment it out:
Set PPslide = PPpres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)

' Assuming the active slide, no need to anywhere:
PP.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (1)

' Change this to use the currently active slide
Set PPslide = PPpres.Slides(1)
Set PPslide = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1) '<-- I get error here.

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
PPslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2 '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
 Set myShape = PPslide.Shapes(PPslide.Shapes.Count)
 
 
  'Set position:
      myShape.Left = 40
      myShape.Top = 180
      myShape.Height = 220
      myShape.Width = 850
'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
PP.Visible = True
PP.Activate
'Clear The Clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Next i
    k = k + 1
```

Comment: Outside of VBA you would normally "Insert Object" and make that object an EXCEL sheet, then paste your range inside that object.  You probably want to accomplish that same sequence with VBA code, so start researching how to embed an EXCEL worksheet into a ppt slide.

Comment: You code sample requires us to do some reconstruction of your macro in order to test it. Here's how to create a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example The first line of your posting adds a new slide. Instead, you would want to modify that to work on a selected slide.

Comment: I updated post, now you can see full code. If you have any questions about code, I can answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to paste into the currently active slide:

```
' Here you're adding a new slide, which you've said you don't want.
' Comment it out:
' Set PPslide = PPpres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)

' Assuming the active slide, no need to anywhere:
' PP.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (1)

' Change this to use the currently active slide
' Set PPslide = PPpres.Slides(1)
Set PPslide = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1)

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
PPslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2 '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
 Set myShape = PPslide.Shapes(PPslide.Shapes.Count)
```

Comment: I tried but I get error, "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: On what line?  And how have you DIMmed PPslide and myShape. We may need to see the rest of the code, or at least enough to repro the problem.

Comment: I will updated full code, you can see PPslide and Myshape. Also error is in this line: Set PPslide = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1)  P.S i am unable to edit code.. it says: Suggested edit queue is full

Comment: On the line just before the line with error, you have already set a reference to the slide; try simply commenting out the line that causes the error.